# an error occurred when accessing the isolotedstorage WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I'm trying load image from Picture Hub through this...

```
void photoChooser_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {           
        try
        {
            var imageVar = new BitmapImage();
            imageVar.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);           
            var b = new WriteableBitmap(imageVar.PixelWidth, imageVar.PixelHeight);
            b.LoadJpeg(toStream(imageVar));//here comes the exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }

Stream toStream(BitmapImage img) 
    {
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)img);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            return stream;
        }
    }
```

Giving **an error occurred when accessing the isolotedstorage**. please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've used looks okay !

```
void photoChooser_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{           
    try
    {
        var imageVar = new BitmapImage();
        imageVar.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);           
        var b = new WriteableBitmap(imageVar.PixelWidth, imageVar.PixelHeight);
        b.LoadJpeg(toStream(imageVar));//here comes the exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }


}
```

Stream toStream(BitmapImage img) 
    {
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)img);

```
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {

        bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Try reconnecting USB !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to:

1. Get image from a chooser (stream)
2. Create a bitmap object
3. Write it to another stream
4. Create a WriteableBitmap from that second stream

This is seriously convoluted. All you have to do is this:

```
var imageVar = new BitmapImage();
imageVar.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);           
var b = new WriteableBitmap(imageVar.PixelWidth, imageVar.PixelHeight);
b.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
```

This will get you the photo, but have in mind that if you first create a BitmapImage using the SetSource method, it will limit the size of your photo to be under 2000x2000. Then the WriteableBitmap will also be of that smaller, reduced size.

If you wish to create a full sized WriteableBitmap using LoadJpeg method, you need to do this:

```
//DO SOMETHING TO GET THE PIXEL WIDTH AND PIXEL HEIGHT OF PICTURE BASED JUST ON THE STREAM, FOR EXAMPLE USE EXIF READER: http://igrali.com/2011/11/01/reading-and-displaying-exif-photo-data-on-windows-phone/ OR SEE MORE ABOUT LOADING A LARGE PHOTO HERE: http://igrali.com/2012/01/03/how-to-open-and-work-with-large-photos-on-windows-phone/          
var b = new WriteableBitmap(PixelWidth, PixelHeight);
b.LoadJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);
```

That will load you the full sized JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

You didnot specify, what you want to perform after fetching the Image.
If all you want is to display the image in your app, then you follow this code:

In your try block, simply add this

```
var imageVar = new BitmapImage();
imageVar.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = imageVar;
this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(img);
```